# What is this almost spherical red flower with thin, hair-like, petals?

Tags: identification, flowers

I saw this flower at the Cecil B. Day Butterfly Center in Callaway Gardens. Please help me identify it.

[image: flower]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This plant is [Calliandra haematocephala](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calliandra_haematocephala) or the Pink Powderpuff. This plant is considered to be a broadleaf evergreen in USDA zone 9 to 11 and grows up to 6 feet ( 2 m tall).

From [here](http://www.missouribotanicalgarden.org/PlantFinder/PlantFinderDetails.aspx?kempercode=a493)

> Native to Borneo, red powder puff is an evergreen shrub or small tree.
>   It was formerly included in the legume or pea family,.... It typically
>   grows 10-15’ tall in its native habitat and is a very popular
>   flowering shrub in central and southern Florida where it will survive
>   year-round in the ground. Bipinnately compound leaves (5-10 pairs of
>   leaflets per pinna) open copper-pink but mature to dark green.
>   Raspberry-like flower buds open to hemispherical red powder puff
>   flower heads (to 3” across) consisting of masses of scarlet stamens.
>   Blooms primarily in fall and winter, but sporadic additional bloom may
>   occur throughout the rest of the year. Variations in flower color
>   exist, with some pink and white forms being available. Calliandra
>   comes from the Greek words kallos meaning beauty and andros meaning

I last saw this in a greenhouse where it was an open shrub that was subject to [mealybug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mealybug).